# Counts, bars, bins for each pandas DataFrame histogram subplot

Tags: count, histogram, density-plot

I am making separate histograms of travel distance per departure hour. However, for making further calculations I'd like to have the value of each bin in a histogram, for all histograms.

Up until now, I have the following:

```
    df['Distance'].hist(by=df['Departuretime'], color = 'red', 
            edgecolor = 'black',figsize=(15,15),sharex=True,density=True)
```

This creates in my case a figure with 21 small histograms.

With single histograms, I'd paste `counts, bins, bars =`  in front of the entire line and the variable `counts` would contain the data I was looking for, however, in this case it does not work.

Ideally I'd like a dataframe or list of some sort for each histogram, containing the density values of the bins. I hope someone can help me out! Thanks in advance!

Edit:

[Data I'm using, about 2500 columns of this, Distance is float64, the Departuretime is str](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICXZE.png)

[Histogram output I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q002.png)

Of all these histograms I want to know the y-axis value of each bar, preferably in a dataframe with the distance binning as rows and the hours as columns

Comment: Can you pls provide the code you have written, data used (in text/table form), the histograms you are seeing now and what is the change you are expecting

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I made an edit. Distance is float64, the Departuretime is str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the 'cut' function you can withdraw the requested data directly from your dataframe, instead of from the graph. This is less error-sensitive.

```
df['DistanceBin'] = pd.cut(df['Distance'], bins=10)
```

Then, you can use pivot_table to obtain a table with the counts for each combination of DistanceBin and Departuretime as rows and columns respectively as you asked.

```
df.pivot_table(index='DistanceBin', columns='Departuretime', aggfunc='count')
```